# Perl script to find Repeating patterns and number of occurence in a file?

Tags: perl

I am looking for a Perl Script that will efficiently find repeating patterns and their number of occurrence in a file.

Sample File Input:

```
1
2
3
1
2
5
1
2
4
```

Sample output
The repeating Patterns are

```
1 - 3

2 - 3

1 2 - 3
```

Comment: Hello. Please see [ask] for what makes a good question. For starters - it pays to remember that Stack Overflow isn't a coding service, it's a site for programmers to assist each other solving problems. To that end - showing some attempt at solving it yourself is a good thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. I did figure a way to solve this but its complexity will be exponential. SO I wanted to know if there is some better ways to solve the same :)

Comment: Answer - probably. But your examples are still unclear as to how it 'works' - which code illustrates too, even if it is exponential. In the above, I'm unclear how '1-3' is a repeating pattern, if 3 only occurs once.

Comment: If you have working code and you're not sure if it it could be better, maybe post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. If you have a specific question with some specific code and input, post the smallest working example of it here

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to put a limit to the pattern size otherwise complexity will be a problem.
Given that P is the pattern size, N the file(list) length the complexity of my solution should be O(N*P)

```
my $window_size = 5;
my @input = qw ( 1 2 3 1 2 5 1 2 4 );


my %result;
my %windows;

foreach my $inp (@input) {
    for my $win_size (1..$window_size){
        push @{ $windows{$win_size} } , $inp;
        shift @{ $windows{$win_size} } if scalar @{ $windows{$win_size} } > $win_size;
        my $win_string = join(' ', @{ $windows{$win_size} });
        $result{$win_string} += 1 if scalar @{ $windows{$win_size} } == $win_size;
    }
}

foreach (sort { length $a <=> length $b } keys %result) {
   print "$_ \t\t $result{$_}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way by using `hash`. Following code will give you the *repeating patterns and their number of occurrence* in a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %count;

open my $fh, "<", "abc.txt" or die $!;

while(my $line = <$fh>)
{
    chomp $line;
    $count{$line} += 1;
}
close $fh;

foreach my $pattern (sort keys %count)
{
    next if ($count{$pattern} == 1);
    print $pattern . " - " . $count{$pattern} . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1 - 3
2 - 3
```

Comment: I think OP wants to count also multiple lines (ie. 1 2,  2 3, 1 2 3, ...)

Comment: @Toto: May be. But OP is not cleared about it. My code is based on OPs' this line _repeating patterns and their number of occurrence_.

Comment: Sure, it isn't really clear, but the third line of his example lists `1 2 - 3`, I guess this is sayint that couple of lines 1 & 2 appears 3 times. That's why he said that the complexity is exponential.

Comment: Hmm, But OP didn't explain about this and example is unclear.